# C# how to refactor class by adding template

Tags: c#, generics, refactoring

I want to refactor this class to handle more types of objects

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass  
{
  public void method()
  {
    IT obj= new ConcreteObject();
    //Some code
  }
}
```

Into this:

```
public class MyClass<T> : IMyClass 
  where T: IT, new()
{
  public void method()
  {
    IT obj= new T();
    //Some code
  }
}
```

Because now more functionality is available in the new `ConcreteObject`.

The problem is that a lot of projects use `MyClass` and I don't want them to change or even know there was a change.

I just want the default value of `T` to be the `ConcreteObject`.

How this should be handled?

Comment: "The problem is that a lot of project use this class and I don't want them to change or even know there was a change."

Which class are you talking about? IMyClass or ConcreteObject?

Comment: @Ouarzy So far no project  is aware of the ConcreteObject, They only use IMyClass.

Comment: Good news otherwise you would have no solution. For that I guess @Sefe answer would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the generic version of `MyClass` an intermediate of the non-generic version. As long as you are careful in your refactoring process, the class interface of the non-generic class will stay the same:

```
public class MyClass<T> : IMyClass 
  where T: IT, new()
{
  public void method()
  {
    IT obj= new T();
    //Some code
  }
}

public class MyClass : MyClass<ConcreteObject> 
{
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/6859983/sefe I accepted your answer because it's clear, easy and it works just fine. Thank you!